# Is $\gcd(2^m-1,2^n-1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$ related to a Hensel lift?

Tags: soft-question, modular-arithmetic, hensels-lemma

> Is $\gcd(2^m-1,2^n-1) = 2^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$ related to a Hensel lift?

They look similar in respect of having the same "modulo some power of $p$" component. Are they both examples of a "lift"?

Comment: http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=16019